# Uploading .zip file to Cloudinary using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, cloudinary

I have Cloudinary API added to my Rails 6 application. Photo extensions and video extension uploads work great. .zip extensions do not. I've run into two errors while trying to upload a zip file.

- CloudinaryException (Unsupported ZIP file):
- ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'type' for Photo.)

In my controller for uploading the zip file, I tried to upload a zip file in different ways.

First I tried

```
  @value = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:downloadable],
  folder: "game_zip", resource_type: :raw)
```

Second I tried

```
  @value = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:downloadable])
```

Third I tried

```
@value = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:downloadable],
:resource_type => :auto)
```

I read in Cloudinary documents that using raw file types is how you can upload zip files, I tried what they recommended, but it's not working. Is there a solution or option that I need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudinary recently updated its security policies, and now restricts both `pdf` and archive file types on new Free accounts.

This can be bypassed by [contacting Cloudinary's support](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new), or by upgrading your account.

Comment: Thank you @brian. They really should add this information in their documentation.